# PHP- Accessing variables created in another method inside an object

Tags: php, oop

inside a computer....Ok, here is my question.

I'm creating a PHP object that will echo out a XML document. I'm putting in a date/time stamp as a default. I'm starting out using the constructor to generate the time stamp.

The roadblock I've hit is how to to use different methods to access the XML document that was created inside the constructor. I'm trying to expand my knowledge about OOP so a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
<?php //XML DOM OBJECT CREATOR 9000

// Create new DOM object
$dom = new Xmlstuff;
$dom->generateError('This is the error');
$dom->addtime();
$dom->generateXML();

    class Xmlstuff extends DOMDocument{

    //Constructor
        public function __construct(){
        //Calling constructor of DOMDocument
        parent::__construct('1.0','utf-8'); 

        } //End of constructor


        function generateError($errorMsg){

            //Generate standard response 
            //Root Node
            $rootNode= $this->createElement('root','');
            $this->appendChild($rootNode);

            //status Node
            $statusNode=$this->createElement('status',' '); 
            $rootNode->appendChild($statusNode);

            //Error Message
            $errorElement=$this->createElement('error' ,$errorMsg); 
            $statusNode->appendChild($errorElement);

            //date
            $dateElement=$this->createElement('date', date("d/m/Y"));
            $statusNode->appendChild($dateElement);

            //time
            //$timeElement=$this->createElement('time', date("H:i:s").' PST');
            //$statusNode->appendChild($timeElement);
            } 


            function addtime(){
            //time
            $timeElement=$this->createElement('time', date("H:i:s").' PST');
            $statusNode->appendChild($timeElement);
            }


            //Function to display generated XML document
            function generateXML(){
            header('Content-Type: text/xml');
            echo $this->saveXML();  
            }

} //End of Class


?>
```

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "different methods to access the XML document"

Comment: Oops I think I posted the wrong code..Anyways. I use generateError() to create a XML document. I'm using addtime() to add a time node the XML doc. I'm trying to figure out how to get the scope right. if I use addtime() is throws errors. I'm assuming since the variables inside the Generate error are not visible between the classes.?

Comment: see my answer about using `$this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are extending the DOMDocument, so anything on DOMDocument you want to access is accessible through $this/self Xmlstuff "is a" DOMDocument

Xmlstuff is an extension of DOMDocument. So anything behaviour or data that DOMDocument contains, your new class Xmlstuff also contains.

The call to `parent::__construct();` is just saying, after I've done specific initialization for the Xmlstuff class, do all the initialization needed for the DOMDocument.

Any data/functions declared in the DOMDocument class as public or protected will be inherited by your Xmlstuff class.

Looking further at your code, the addtime function doesn't have access to $statusNode, if you want access to it (the $statusNode created in generateError), then you need to make it a member variable. `$this->statusNode`.

```
function addtime(){
    //time
    $timeElement=$this->createElement('time', date("H:i:s").' PST');
    $this->statusNode->appendChild($timeElement);
}
```

Note: you will have to create it as well in the generateError function.

Additionally to make you code tidier, you should initialize $this->statusNode in your constructor. The reason being a class should hide its implementation details (it should be a black box to anyone that wants to use it). If someone called the function `addTime()` before calling `generateError()` then `$this->statusNode` will not have been created yet.

i.e. Add this line to your constructor:

```
$this->statusNode = $this->createElement('status', ' ');
```

replace this line from `generateError()`

```
$statusNode=$this->createElement('status',' ');
```

with

```
$statusNode = $this->statusNode;
```

Comment: Thank Jacob, I posted the wrong code. The version I wanted, I had put everything into the constructor, but not very tidy. You answer helped me out a lot. vote+

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i read this right, but is this what youw anted?  How to access a value created by the method... outside of the class (maybe from a different class)?

```
$dom = new Xmlstuff;
$dom->setValue('Test');
echo $dom->xmlDocument;

class Xmlstuff extends DOMDocument{

    public $xmlDocument = "Initial Value";

    function setValue($val){
        $this->xmlDocument = $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've created the XML document inside of the generateError() method/function. If I try to use addtime() it throws errors. I'm trying to figure out how to get the scope right.   I is confoozed.